# Not sure how to create global Mysqli connection for my two classes

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have asked this question before and I was slapped on the hand for duplicate questions... But interestingly the duplicate questions answer is something I don't understand and have no clue how to implement it in my code.

The answer to the "duplicate" question mentions PDO connection and currently something I have no clue of or understands.

I have figured out to, with help, write two classes, One to submit data into the the MySql database, the other to search the columns of the MySql database.

My problem is to actually place both the classes in one php file and allow them both to use only one connection class.

Both these classes are different written in different format and I am trying to understand how to combine them into one, or at least use the one connection class instead of each using its own connection function that, I know, is bad php standard...

The Answer I was pointed to mention the use of this:

```
  $pdo = new PDO('something');
  function foo() {
     global $pdo;
     $pdo->prepare('...');
  }
```

My problem is this... I am not using PDO... 
Please assist and explain what I need to change to make these two classes to use one Db connection...

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');



function db_connect() {

    // Define connection as a static variable, to avoid connecting more than once 
    static $connection;

    // Try and connect to the database, if a connection has not been established yet
    if(!isset($connection)) {
        $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','user','pass','resrequest_db1');
    }

    // If connection was not successful, handle the error
    if($connection === false) {
        // Handle error - notify administrator, log to a file, show an error screen, etc.
        return mysqli_connect_error(); 
    }
    return $connection;
}

function db_query($query) {
    // Connect to the database
    $connection = db_connect();

    // Query the database
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

    return $result;
}    


class booking
{
  private $error;
  private $success;
  private $form_data = array();

  function __construct()
  {

      //check if the booking form has been submitted
      if (isset($_POST['submit_form'])) {

          foreach ($_POST as $field => $value)
              $this->form_data[$field] = $value;

          //start perform the validation once the form has been submitted
          $this->validateInformation();
      }

      //check to see if the mail has been sent, and then display a success message

      if (isset($_GET['m']) && $_GET['m'] == "s") {
          $this->error = "<div class='alert alert-success'>Thank You! We received your booking</div>";
      }

      //display error if any
      if (!empty ($this->error) || !empty ($this->success))
          $this->displayMessage(!empty($this->error) ? $this->error : (!empty($this->success) ? $this->success : ''), false);

  }

  /********************************************************
   * This function retrieves data for booking form
   * and performs validation
   *******************************************************/
  private function validateInformation()
  {
      // check if person provided his name
      if (empty($this->form_data['b_name'])) {
          $this->error .= '<li>You must enter your name.</li>';
      }

      // check if person provided his email
      if (empty($this->form_data['email'])) {
          $this->error .= '<li>You must enter your email.</li>';
      }

      // check if the email address provided by user is in correct format
      if (!empty($this->form_data['email'])) {
          if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $this->form_data['email'])) {
              $this->error .= '<li>Email format your entered is not valid.</li>';
          }
      }

      // check if contact_number is empty
      if (empty($this->form_data['contact_number'])) {
          $this->error .= '<li>Please enter a contact number.</li>';
      }
      //Check for a valid phone number  (Only numbers between 7 & 20 caracters)
      if (!empty($this->form_data['phone'])) {
          $phone = $this->form_data['phone'];
          $pattern = "/^[0-9\_]{10,20}/";
          if (preg_match($pattern,$phone)){ 
            $phone = $this->form_data['phone'];}
            else{ $errors[] = 'Your Phone number can only be numbers.';}
          } else {$errors[] = 'You forgot to enter your Phone number.';}

      // check if person provided total rooms
      if (empty($this->form_data['nr_rooms'])) {
          $this->error .= '<li>Indicate total rooms.</li>';
      }

      // check if person provided arrival date
      if (empty($this->form_data['arrival'])) {
          $this->error .= '<li>Please select arrival date.</li>';
      }

      // check if person provided departure date
      if (empty($this->form_data['departure'])) {
          $this->error .= '<li>Please select departure date.</li>';
      }

      $this->error = (isset($this->error)) ? "<div class='alert alert-danger'><h4 class='alert-heading'>Attention!</h4>$this->error</div>" : '';

      // if no errors are found, get ready to send the mail
      if (empty($this->error)) {
          $this->dbInsert();
      }
  }

  /********************************************************
   * This function inserts data into Db
   *******************************************************/

  private function dbInsert()
  {
    $b_name=$this->form_data['b_name'];
    $email=$this->form_data['email'];
    $contact_number=$this->form_data['contact_number'];
    $nr_rooms=$this->form_data['nr_rooms'];
    $arrival=$this->form_data['arrival'];
    $departure=$this->form_data['departure'];

    // An insertion query.
    $result = db_query("INSERT INTO bookings (b_name,email,contact_number,nr_rooms,arrival,departure)
            VALUES ('$b_name','$email','$contact_number','$nr_rooms','$arrival','$departure')");
    if($result === false) {
      // Handle failure - log the error, notify administrator, etc.
      $error ="<div class='alert alert-danger'><h4 class='alert-heading'>Attention!</h4>
              Databse error!!!</div>";
    } else {
          $redirect_page = "index.php?m=s";
          header('Location: ' . $redirect_page);
          exit();
    }
  }

  /********************************************************
   * This function displays error if any
   *******************************************************/

  private function displayMessage($error, $exit = true)
  {
      if (!empty($error)) :
          include_once(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) . '/' . 'header.php');
          echo $error;
          if ($exit) {
              include_once(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) . '/' . 'footer.php');
              exit();
          }
      endif;
  }

  /********************************************************
   * This function will store the submitted data in case
   * of any error so user does not have to re enter the
   * information which he/she already provided
   *******************************************************/

  public function fetchPost($var)
  {
      return empty($this->form_data[$var]) ? '' : $this->form_data[$var];
  }

}

$booking = new booking();

class search {
  /**
   * MySQLi connection
   * @access private
   * @var object
   */
  private $mysqli;

  /**
   * Constructor
   *
   * This sets up the class
   */
  public function __construct() {
    // Connect to our database and store in $mysqli property
    $this->connect();
  }
  /**
   * Database connection
   * 
   * This connects to our database
   */

  private function connect() {
    $config = parse_ini_file('config.ini');   //<--------------------------- Not to be placed in root directory, done for Resrequest demo
    $this->mysqli = new mysqli( 'localhost', $config['username'],$config['password'],$config['dbname'] );
  }

  /**
   * Search routine
   * 
   * Performs a search
   * 
   * @param string $search_term The search term
   * 
   * @return array/boolen $search_results Array of search results or false
   */
  public function search($search_term) {
    // Sanitize the search term to prevent injection attacks
    $sanitized = $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($search_term);

    // Run the query
    $query = $this->mysqli->query("
      SELECT b_name, email, contact_number, arrival, departure
      FROM bookings
      WHERE b_name LIKE '%{$sanitized}%'
      OR email LIKE '%{$sanitized}%' OR contact_number LIKE '%{$sanitized}%' 
      OR arrival LIKE '%{$sanitized}%' OR departure LIKE '%{$sanitized}%'
    ");

    // Check results
    if ( ! $query->num_rows ) {
      return false;
    }

    // Loop and fetch objects
    while( $row = $query->fetch_object() ) {
      $rows[] = $row;
    }

    // Build our return result
    $search_results = array(
      'count' => $query->num_rows,
      'results' => $rows,
    );

    return $search_results;
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: First you need a one file called like connection.php, here you have the connection to mysql, then in your other php just include the connection.php file

Comment: @bicho it will be the same as having the "incorrect" connection function as I currently have on top of this script.

I have extracted those two functions as 1. public and 1 private function out the booking class and still the booking class is working 100%, but when I extract the connect class out of the search class the search class is not working.

Answer (score 0):

this is a common approach to handle this kind of stuff.
Please try:

```
class Database {
    private static $instance;
    private $db;

    private function __construct() {
        $this->db = mysqli_connect('localhost','user','pass','resrequest_db1');
    }

    public static function getInstance() {
        if(self::$instance === null) {
            self::$instance = new Database();
        }
        return self::$instance->db;
    }
}

class MyClass {
private $db = null;
public function __construct($db){
    $this->db = $db
}
.... your code here 
}

// you create the unique connection here. 
 $db = Database::getInstance();
// call of the class
 $myClass = new MyClass($db);
```

Comment: I did make the changes as you suggest but now get errors when calling the class as you suggest at the end:
When I add $search=search($db); the error is:
Fatal error: Call to undefined function search()
Same for $booking
Fatal error: Call to undefined function booking()

Comment: But you need to change your classes. you need to pass the Connection object to the class like new MyClass($db); in a class itself you will use $this->db->db_query(.......), if you will use the separate functions you need to pass the DB object to via arguments like function myFoo($db, $someParam)

Comment: $search=search($db); should be $search = new search($db);